# Evolution setup

Tags: evolution

I can't access my email with Evolution.
There is nowhere to enter the ISP password in the setup procedure, only a note to say that the password will be asked for at first login. But there is no first login with no password.

There must be a simple explanation, I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Once you've finished the setup of a new account, Evolution usually tries to retrieve mail immediately, and thus should ask you for the password -- it always did for me. That's what's meant with the "first login". You also could try pushing the send/receive button to trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Since updating my Ubuntu, Evolution is an absolute mess. Cannot open, reply, forward a second message opened. Have to restart Evolution. Cannot open a draft at all.